# Saving the weight of one layer in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I would like to save the weight of a model, but not the whole model like this:

```
torch.save(model, 'model.pth')
```

But rather, just one layer. for example, suppose, I have defined one layer like this:

```
self.conv_up3 = convrelu(256 + 512, 512, 3, 1)
```

How do I save the weight of only this layer. And also how do I load it for this layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to save/get parameters of the specific layer:

```
specific_params = self.conv_up3.state_dict()
# save/manipulate `specific_params` as you want
```

And similarly, to load the params to that specific layer:

```
self.conv_up3.load_state_dict(params)
```

You can do this  because each layer is a neural network (`nn.Module` instance) in itself.